# QGIS crashes when using r.surf.gauss after installing new version

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I installed the newest version of QGIS (3.30.1) after uninstalling an older version that I had (3.28.3). Now I'm having an issue with my r.surf.gauss plugin crashing the program entirely when trying to apply a gaussian blur to my raster. Any idea as to why this is happening? Is it because I improperly uninstalled my last version?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with a fresh QGIS profile? Setting -> User Profiles -> New Profile...